# Animação Slide para

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema no slide , ele faz as transações de imagem mas quando chega na ultima ele para e não volta para a primeira imagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ele para exatamente nessa imagem

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


#topo {
 background:url(../imagens/topo.png); 
 position:inherit;
 width:1024px;
 height:190px;
 border-bottom:none;
 margin:auto;
 

}

#logo {
 float:left;
 background:url(../imagens/logoc.png);
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 left:155px;
 width:541px;
 height:133px;
}
 
#fundoinicial {
 background-image:url(../imagens/fundoof.png);
 width:1024px;
 height:1080px;
 margin:auto;
 
}

#menufundo {
 background:url(../imagens/menu.png);
 position:relative;
 width:1024px;
 height:27px;
 margin:auto;
 border:1px solid #000000 ;
 
 
}


#ul li a{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-style:normal;
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height:0px;
 padding:10px;
    margin:4px 0 0 52px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 float:left;
 
 
}

#ul li a:hover{
 text-shadow:0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black; 
 font-size:20px;
    color:black;
}

.galeria{
 width:850px;
 height:300px;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
 border: 15px solid #999;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin-left:70px;
 margin-top:50px;
  
}

.foto {
 position:absolute;
 opacity:0;
 animation-name:slide;
 animation-duration:50s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
 5% {
  opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
  opacity:1;
 }
 50% {
  opacity:1;
 }
  
}

.foto:nth-child(1) {
 
} 
 
.foto:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay:5s;
 
} 
 
.foto:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay:10s;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Alfatec</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/ico.png" type="imagem/x-png" />
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(../PLANILHAS%20CAIO/projeto/imagens/fundo.jpg);
}
 
</style>
</head>


<body>

<div id="logo"></div><!--div final do logo-->
<div id="topo"></div><!--div final topo-->
<div id="menufundo">

<nav id="ul">    
          <ul>            
           <li><a href="#">Página Inicial   </a></li> 
           <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Áreas de Cobertura</a></li> 
           <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
       </ul>
</nav>
</div>

         
<div id ="fundoinicial">
<section class="galeria">
 <img class="foto" src="imagens/img1.jpg" />
 <img class="foto" src="imagens/img2.jpg" /> 
 <img class="foto" src="imagens/img3.jpg" />
</section>
</div><!--div final menufundo-->         
   
                                
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque uma função em javascript

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("foto");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); //  2 segundos
}
```

```html
<div id ="fundoinicial">
<section class="galeria">
 <img class="foto" src="http://kithomepage.com/images/Imagem001.jpg" />
 <img class="foto" src="http://kithomepage.com/images/Imagem002.jpg" /> 
 <img class="foto" src="http://kithomepage.com/images/Imagem003.jpg" />
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado , Abraços !!!